# regex php: find everything in div

Tags: php, regex, html, extract

I'm trying to find eveything inside a div using regexp. I'm aware that there probably is a smarter way to do this - but I've chosen regexp.

so currently my regexp pattern looks like this:

```
$gallery_pattern = '/<div class="gallery">([\s\S]*)<\/div>/';
```

And it does the trick - somewhat.

The problem is if i have two divs after each other - like this.

```
<div class="gallery">text to extract here</div>
<div class="gallery">text to extract from here as well</div>
```

I want to extract the information from both divs, but my problem, when testing, is that im not getting the text in between as a result but instead:

```
"text to extract here </div>  
<div class="gallery">text to extract from here as well"
```

So to sum up. It skips the first end of the div. and continues on to the next. 
The text inside the div can contain `<`, `/` and linebreaks. just so you know!

Does anyone have a simple solution to this problem? Im still a regexp novice.

Comment: I've been discussing the same w/ my friend few weeks ago. The problem is when you have tags like these "<div class="gallery">some text<div>other text</div></div>", it is hard to make the expression not stop on the first </div>

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What about something like this :

```
$str = <<<HTML
<div class="gallery">text to extract here</div>
<div class="gallery">text to extract from here as well</div>
HTML;

$matches = array();
preg_match_all('#<div[^>]*>(.*?)</div>#s', $str, $matches);

var_dump($matches[1]);
```

Note the '?' in the regex, so it is "not greedy".

Which will get you :

```
array
  0 => string 'text to extract here' (length=20)
  1 => string 'text to extract from here as well' (length=33)
```

This should work fine... If you don't have imbricated divs ; if you do... Well... actually : are you really sure you want to use rational expressions to parse HTML, which is quite not that rational itself ?

Comment: @Filip : I would recommend using DOM and loadHTML too, actually -- I did several times, in other answers (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1274020/extract-form-fields-using-regex/1274074#1274074 for instance) : HTML is not something that can be properly parsed with regexes... not rational enough, I suppose ^^

Answer (score 12):

You shouldn't be using regex to parse HTML when there's a convenient DOM library:

```
$str = '
<div class="gallery">text to extract here</div>
<div class="gallery">text to extract from here as well</div>
';

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($str);
$divs = $doc->getElementsByTagName('div');

if ( count($divs ) ) {
    foreach ( $divs as $div ) {
    echo $div->nodeValue . '<br>';
    }
}
```