# How to extract contents of a div from a string using regx

Tags: php, regex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [regex php: find everything in div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1352078/regex-php-find-everything-in-div)

I have string like

```
$str= 'hello asd asd 
<div class="name">Sunil</div>' asdasd
asdasdasd
asdasdasdasd;
```

I would like to get the content of the div name . (means I want to get Sunil ) using reg ex..

Please, help me.

Comment: That's not a PHP string.. (displaced quotes)

Comment: If the content of the `div` may contain markup (like other `div`) then it will be impossible to do with regexes. Is it the case or the content is always text without markup ? Moreover you're piece of code doesn't look valid.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use regex to search recursively, as it has no way of expressing recursion. This is why people write parsers.

I believe what you are looking for is http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

Comment: There are recursive regular expressions. It's just not a reasonable effort (and answered in dupes). Also please post as comment if it doesn't match the question tag.