# Programmatically delete everything before a HTML node?

Tags: python, html, parsing, dom, beautifulsoup

I am trying to create a corpus of data from a set of .html pages I have stored in a directory.

These HTML pages have lots of info I don't need.

This info is all stored before the line

```
<div class="channel">
```

How can I programmatically remove all of the text before

```
<div class="channel">
```

in every HTML file in a folder?

Bonus question for a 50point bounty :

How do I programmatically remove everything AFTER, for example,

```
<div class="footer">
```

?

So if my index.html was previously :

```
<head>
   <title>This is bad HTML</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1> Remove me</h1>
  <div class="channel">
    <h1> This is the good data, keep me</h1>

    <p> Keep this text </p>

  </div>
  <div class="footer">
    <h1> Remove me, I am pointless</h1>
  </div>
</body>
```

After my script runs, I want it to be :

```
  <div class="channel">
    <h1> This is the good data, keep me</h1>

    <p> Keep this text </p>

  </div>
```

Comment: You need only the text in the class channel, nothing else? Then you can use regex: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1352078/regex-php-find-everything-in-div

Comment: @lolka_bolka I need everything above the class "channel" to be removed and everything below the class "footer". Thanks :)

Comment: Do you want to do it with pure javascript?

Comment: @lolka_bolka I'm open in terms of technology used, ideally Python maybe as I am currently trying to learn this :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bit heavy on memory usage, but it works. Basically you open up the directory, get all ".html" files, read them into a variable, find the split point, store the before or after in a variable, and then overwrite the file.

There are probably better ways to do this, nonetheless, but it works.

```
import os

dir = os.listdir(".")

files = []

for file in dir:
    if file[-5:] == '.html':
        files.insert(0, file)


for fileName in files:
    file = open(fileName)
    content = file.read()
    file.close()

    loc = content.find('<div class="channel">')

    newContent = content[loc:]

    file = open(fileName, 'w')
    file.write(newContent)
    file.close()
```

If you wanted to just keep up to a point:

```
newContent = content[0:loc - 1] # I think the -1 is needed, not sure
```

Note that the things you're searching should be kept in a variable, and not hardcoded.

Also, this won't work recursively for file/folder structures, but you can find out how to modify it to do that very easily.

Comment: Thank you, this is fantastic. Exactly what I was looking for. Is it possible for me to "store everything that is past <div class="channel">, as your script currently does - but adapt it so it only stores up until, for example, <div class="end_here"> ? Thanks

Comment: Use the same method. Find the end point, and use the line I mentioned that's for keeping up to a certain point (the `[0:loc - 1]` code). So basically find and chop the beginning. Then find and chop the end.

Comment: I would always use a `with open(filename, mode) as file:` construction, to ensure closing the file on unforeseen errors.
   
 
Then I would use `if file.endswith(file_extension)` instead of magic number.
 
  
Finally I would use a generator to retrieve all filenames recursivly.

Comment: @David Thank you very much - just from eyeing the code, there is one small piece I don't understand and was hoping you could help me with. "newContent = content[loc:]". Is this not assigning everything before the loc variable to newContent? So all of the HTML from the beginning up until loc would be stored in here, rather than everything after loc? Have I mixed up how ":" is used or misunderstood? Thanks :)

Comment: If you do, `content[0:5]` you will get the first five characters. Do, `content[5:]` and you will get the 5th character to the end, do `content[-5:]` you will get from the 5th to last element to the end. Do, `content[:5]` and you will get a syntax error. :)

Comment: @David I understand, thank you very much :). When I try to run this code now, I get the error :IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:

Comment: At which line, do you have it pointing to the correct directory? Or did you make a typo, or perhaps forget to use either single quotes or double slashes in the path name?

Comment: @David At line 14,     file = open(fileName), it is pointing to the correct directory and using the correct quotes :)

Comment: @David So you need to have this .py stored in the same directory, or else append on the address on line 14 like so :     "file = open("C:/Users/Simon/Files/" + fileName)". Thanks ! :)

Comment: @David It now runs with no error, but makes no changes to any of the files! :)

Comment: Are you putting files into the files array? Do a print statement to output each one that gets added. The code I posted was tested. It wasn't a freehand.

Answer (score 0):

to remove everything above   and everything below 
that means the only thing left should be this section:

```
<div class="channel">
    <h1> This is the good data, keep me</h1>
    <p> Keep this text </p>
</div>
```

rather than thinking to remove the unwanted, it would be easier to just extract the wanted.
you can easily extract channel div using XML parser such as DOM

Comment: My problem is that the div I want to keep is named differently across the different .html files :)

Answer (score 0):

You've not mentioned a language in the question - the post is tagged with `python` so this answer might still be out of context, but I'll give a `php` solution that could likely easily be rewritten in another language.

```
$html='....'; // your page
$search='<div class="channel">';
$components = explode($search,$html); // [0 => before the string, 1 => after the string]
$result = $search.$components[1];
return $result;
```

To do the reverse is fairly easy too; simply take the value of `$components[0]` after altering `$search` to your `<div class="footer">` value.

If you happen to have the `$search` string cropping up multiple times:

```
$html='....'; // your page
$search='<div class="channel">';
$components = explode($search,$html); // [0 => before the string, 1 => after the string]
unset($components[0]);
$result = $search.implode($search,$components);
return $result;
```

Someone who knows `python` better than I do feel free to rewrite and take the answer!