# How to return a regular expression match in PHP, instead of replacing

Tags: php, preg-replace

I'm trying to extract the first src attribute of an image in a block of HTML text like this:

```
Lorem ipsum <img src="http://example.com/img.jpg" />consequat.
```

I have no problem creating the regular expression to match the src attribute, but how do I **return** the first matched src attribute, instead of **replacing** it?

From pouring over the PHP manual, it seems like [preg_filter()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-filter.php) would do the trick, but I can't rely on end users having a PHP version greater than 5.3.

All the other PHP regular expression functions seem to be variations of preg_match(), returning a Boolean value, or preg_replace, which replaces the match with something. Is there a straightforward way to **return** a regular expression match in PHP?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can use the third parameter of [`preg_match`](http://php.net/preg_match) to know what was matched *(it's an array, passed by reference)*:

```
int preg_match  ( string $pattern  , 
    string $subject  [, array &$matches  [, 
    int $flags  [, int $offset  ]]] )
```

> If matches  is provided, then it is
> filled with the results of search.
> `$matches[0]` will contain the text that
> matched the full pattern, `$matches[1]`
> will have the text that matched the
> first captured parenthesized
> subpattern, and so on.

For instance, with this portion of code:

```
$str = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, adipisicing <img src="http://example.com/img.jpg" />consequat.';

$matches = array();
if (preg_match('#<img src="(.*?)" />#', $str, $matches)) {
    var_dump($matches);
}
```

You'll get this output:

```
array
  0 => string '<img src="http://example.com/img.jpg" />' (length=37)
  1 => string 'http://example.com/img.jpg' (length=23)
```

*(Note that my regex is overly simplistic -- and that regex are generally not "the right tool" when it comes to extracting data from some HTML string...)*

Comment: excellent, thanks.  btw, what is "the right tool" to extract data from an HTML string?

Comment: you're welcome :-) ;; that's a tricky question ^^ I you have a full HTML document, I kinda like the idea of using DOMDocument::loadHTML (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1274020/extract-form-fields-using-regex/1274074#1274074 for some thoughts I posted some time ago) -- but there are also other solutions

Answer (score 0):

The "right tool" for parsing parsable HTML text is a DOM parser. I recommend DOMDocument with its powerful ally XPath.

By searching for the first img tag with a src attribute using `evaluate()` (instead of `query()`), you can directly call for the result as a string value using `string()` around the path.

This is more intuitive and reliable than regex. For regex to avoid quoting differences and exclude attributes like `data-src`, the patternneeda to grow (uglier).

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/MHCIa))

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($str);
echo (new DOMXPath($dom))->evaluate('string(//img/@src)');
```

Result:

```
http://example.com/img.jpg
```

---

If you have a compelling reason to use regex and want to be able to differentiate between img tags with a src value, with an empty src value, and strings with no img or src, then `preg_filter()` is a direct tool which doesn't generate an array. See three examples in my [Demo](https://3v4l.org/H2tek) link.

```
var_export(
    preg_filter('/.*?<img(?= ).*? src=([\'"])((?:(?!\1).)*)\1.*/ius', '$2', $str)
);
```