# PHP: How to get a string from between the first two occurences of character

Tags: php

So let's say that I have the following code:

```
$var = '-77-randomtext-moretext.extension'
```

So that nothing in the variable is fixed, except for the hyphens ( - ), and the extension.

Then let's say that I need to strore the '-77-' part as a string.
'-77-' meaning anything in between the first two hyphens, including the hyphens themselves.

How could I do this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1715854/how-to-return-a-regex-match-in-php-instead-of-replacing

Comment: @Joseph - ["Some people, when confronted with a problem, think  “I know, I'll use regular expressions.”   Now they have two problems."](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: @Lix - [And some people, when confronted with regular expressions, think "I know, I'll use a catchy quote that I remember". Now they have added nothing to the discussion.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1098296/are-regular-expressions-worth-the-hassle)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The two primary ways to do that would be either `explode` or `preg_filter`.

Split:

```
$varArray = explode( '-', $var );
$string77 = '-' . $varArray[1] . '-'; // equals '-77-'
```

preg_filter;

```
$string77 = preg_filter( '/^(-.+-).*$/', '$1', $varArray ); // equals '-77-', or NULL if the string doesn't match
```

The `split` method is quicker, but less reliable. `preg_filter` will ensure you always get either the data you want, or a NULL if it doesn't exist, but requires more processing.

Comment: Ended up using the explode one.
Thanks so much, this was really a difficult task for me.

Answer (score 1):

You could use:

```
$parts = explode('-', $var);
$txt = '-' . $parts[1] . '-';
```

Comment: The needed element is the second in the array, not the first.

Comment: Use `ltrim` or `trim` to get rid of the first hyphen, then it will work as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Use the distance between two `strpos()` calls and get the `substr()` based on those positions:

```
$var = '-77-randomtext-moretext.extension';
$first_pos = strpos($var,'-');

$second_pos = strpos($var,'-',($first_pos+1)); //we offset so we find the second 
$length = ($second_pos+1) - $first_pos; //get the length of the string between these points
echo  substr($var,$first_pos,$length);
```

You could also use a regex expression (`preg_match()`) or use the `explode()` approach:

```
$pieces = explode('-',$var);
$results = '-'.$pieces[0].'-';
```

But this only works if you know that the first and second delimiter will be the same.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a regular expression:  /-(.+?)-/

Answer (score 1):

```
$var = '-77-randomtext-moretext.extension';
preg_match('/-(.+?)-/', $var, $matches);
echo $matches[0]; // -77-
```

Comment: The first index of the array returned by `preg_match` is the entire matching string, not the first matched group.

Comment: @RyanP: You should try above code out or should I create a demo for you on codepad ?